# Decompile Kotlin to JAVA

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am a beginner at Android Studio , and I want the main activity to be on java not on kotlin . I tested some solution available on Stack overflow such as:
menu -> tools -> kotlin -> decompile kotlin to java

1. Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode
2. Click on the Decompile button
3. Copy the java code

and always the Decompile button is disabled.

[image]

Comment: From your screenshot I see your Kotlin code has some compilation issues. If you solve them, the button should be enabled again

Comment: This decompile (kotlin->java) will result in some ugly code which might not be really usable straight away.  I see that there is only a few lines of Kotlin code there, so you would be better off to write it from scratch in Java.

Comment: Then why did you enable Kotlin support when creating the project....?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some errors that won't let it compile. If you fix those issues the "Decompile" button will re-enable.

However:

> I want the main activity to be on java not on kotlin

If this is what you want, it's better you write it in Java in the first place.
Chances are the decompiled Java code will be ugly.